# How does @ViewBuilder work in SwiftUI compared to VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image: Pic]

So from what I can see in this pic @ViewBuilder is just gonna let me list views and then combine all that into one view right? Now my question is though how exactly does it combine them? Like if I have a VStack I can also list views in it and it combines all the views but it does this vertically, and an HStack does it horizontally, so what exactly is the @ViewBuilder doing here? How exactly is it "combining" all these views?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This isn't an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, but a good explanation can be found [here](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/12/18/the-power-of-viewbuilder-in-swiftui/).

Comment: I'm not sure why this has accumulated two close votes; not all SO questions have to be limited to a specific, concrete problem in a piece of code. Questions about how things work or the role of some part of a framework have long been on topic here. Answering the narrow question here and pointing to references for more info, as I've tried to do, is a good way to answer such questions concisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so what exactly is the @ViewBuilder doing here?

**TL/DR:** `VStack` is just one concrete use of the view-combining behavior that's provided by `ViewBuilder`.

Many views can take a closure that combines a number of views and returns one view that combines them all. `VStack`, `HStack`, and `ZStack` all do it, of course, but so do `Button`, `Canvas`, `Form`, and `Group`, `Label`, `List`, `Menu`, and many others. They all use `ViewBuilder` to combine their views. `@ViewBuilder` is the reason that they're all limited to 10 subviews, and also the reason you can conditionally include views using `if` in the list. Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on `ViewBuilder` is a good place to start to learn how to use it.

So, `ViewBuilder`'s role is to provide the mechanism for combining views, and `VStack`, `HStack`, etc. decide *how* to combine the views.

> How exactly is it "combining" all these views?

The short, unsatisfying answer is that `ViewBuilder` uses `@resultBuilder` to combine the views you provide. `resultBuilder` is an attribute that helps you combine things, and `ViewBuilder` is only one of many uses of it in SwiftUI; there's also `SceneBuilder`, `CommandBuilder`, and many others.  Explaining result builders is probably a bigger topic than I'd want to cover in a SO answer, but there's plenty of good info out there; look at the [Swift docs on result builders](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID630) for definitive information, and [John Sundell's blog post on the subject for a good example](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/deep-dive-into-swift-function-builders/).

Answer (score 2):

To understand the difference between naked `@ViewBuilder` and a `VStack`, I think it helps to know `@ViewBuilder` creates and returns a `TupleView` which is a type that just combines views but doesn't apply any layout logic to it.

You can see in the snippet below how `padding` and `border` modifiers work differently on `TupleView` and `VStack`: `TupleView` just passes the modifiers to each of the enclosed views, but `VStack` applies them to the resulting stack.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("VStack")
            .font(.headline)
        VStack() {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.blue)
        
        Divider()
        
        Text("TupleView")
            .font(.headline)
        
        TupleView(
            (
                Image(systemName: "globe"),
                Text("Hello, world!")
            )
        )
        .padding()
        .border(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: Results of code snippet]